# Iterate between two dates in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two dates:

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2013,7,27,12,0,0);
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2013,7,30,12,0,0);
```

I want to iterate from fromDate to toDate by incrementing fromDate with a single day and the loop should break when fromDate becomes equal to or greater than the toDate. I have tried this:

```
while(fromDate < toDate)
{
fromDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

But this is an infinite loop and won't stop. How can I do this ?

Comment: @Ben add days returns a date time, it doesn't set the value of the receiver. if it were fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1) it would terminate

Comment: DateTime is immutable. You need to assign the result of calling AddDays back to fromDays, overwriting the previous value. Currently the value is calculated and then discarded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) indeed adds the specified number of days to the date - but the resulting date is *returned as a **new** `DateTime` value*; the original `DateTime` value is not changed.

Therefore, make sure you assign the result of the your operation back to the variable you inspect in your loop condition:

```
while (fromDate < toDate)
{
    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Untested but should work:

```
for(DateTime date = fromDate; date < toDate; date = date.AddDays(1)) {
}
```

Modify the comparison to `<=` if you want to include `toDate` as well.

Comment: For always better then while ;)